# Is it possible to clean install Big Sur on external SSD using M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, big-sur

I’ve done this many times on Intel Macs running macOS Catalina.

On my MacBook Air M1, booting from [bootable installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) works but a few steps in I am asked “Select a user to set as owner of the new volumes”.

**None** I wish I could answer as I am trying to clean install macOS Big Sur on external SSD to compartmentalize use cases.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If this turn out to be a 'one  can not do it' this will be just another reason to stay away from Apple silicone.

Comment: @user3439894 Feel you… currently trying to install Big Sur on external SSD using Intel Mac to later use external SSD on M1 Mac. Will share my findings once experiment is done. That said, install is currently hanging at “macOS Update Assistant” stage. Puzzled.

Comment: See https://eclecticlight.co/2021/07/18/last-week-on-my-mac-the-perils-of-m1-ownership/ for some answers re ownership.  It helps to have the first user on the internal disk to be the first user on the external.

Comment: Implication of Eclectic blog (see previous comment) may be that you must create external boot using an M1 Mac - possible only the same M1 Mac.

Comment: See also https://eclecticlight.co/2021/07/21/owners-and-users-primary-and-secondary-systems-on-m1-macs/