# Is it possible to boot Big Sur installed on external SSD using M1 Mac on Intel mac?

Tags: macos, big-sur

Trying to understand portability of Big Sur installed on external SSD using M1 Mac. Can I boot install on Intel Mac?

Comment: Well done to have installed Big Sur to boot from an external drive! Having got over that hurdle, I expect the answer is yes.  You should experiment and report back!  Read some of the pages here: https://eclecticlight.co/m1-macs/. Just seen your other post - maybe you haven't got an external boot yet.

Comment: @Gilby I haven’t got an external boot yet. As you noticed with my other [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425412/is-it-possible-to-clean-install-big-sur-on-external-ssd-using-m1-mac), I am still puzzled as to how to create a separate compartmentalized macOS environment with its own admins (and owners apparently).

Comment: I don't have a new Mac, but am following Howard Oakley's Eclectic Light blog.  He and MrMacintosh https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-reinstall-macos-on-your-apple-silicon-mac-everything-you-need-to-know/ are the only people I would trust to properly rest and report on that they are doing.